# Is it a good idea to develop a server application using QT?(QT5)

Tags: c++, qt, service

I am a QT/C++ GUI developer, and I am familiar with QT event system, meta-object system, concurrency. And I know that QT has separated QtCore which makes it possible to develop server applications using Qt without linking in any unnecessary GUI-related code.

I am confused about whether it is a idea to develop a server application using QT?It is my first time to develop a server application, so any ideas and suggestions about server application with QT is grateful and welcome.

1.My server application will be running on windows(OS)，and act as an agent: network request forwarding and buffering, packaging device operations(to provide a unified interface).

2.Need to support 2000 clients concurrent access, so I am worried about whether the event system or signals and qthread are good enough?

Comment: you need to put your requirement as a question .. what do you mean by server application ?? what it will do .. be specific

Comment: Generally speaking there is nothing that will prevent you from developing server-side of your app using Qt especially if clients are developed using Qt too and you will use QtNetwork to connect clients to the server.

Comment: Sounds too opinion-based.

Comment: Qt5 is well tested and probably less error prone than anything you code by yourself. If you take it from Qt, you don't have to test it(because it already is).

Comment: I using QTcpServer / QTcpSocket and i like it. I do not know how it can stand up to 2000 customers but in my opinion there should be no problem. I make each customer in QThread and I do not have any problems. Also I have a running server on a service.

Comment: @Taz742 I have problem about details:can QT shield the not related event like  button and mouse events for this application? I know in the gui,QT will accept all the event from the system, and make a event for each of them.

Comment: I have production-tested server code using Qt for modularization (signals/slots instead of direct callbacks between modules), TCP/IP, Database access, xml an json support and enum <> string conversions thanks to moc. I cannot say anything about performance relative to using boost.asio/signal/etc, but overall it never became a concern to me. Imo, if you are 100% sure you're using C++, and are already familiar with Qt, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem in your scenario is not Qt, I would say it is C/C++.
Server-side services usually need a very high [fault tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tolerance).

With languages like PHP, many Java libraries, etc. that kind of comes built-in.

With C++, it does not. One call resulting in an error that you did not remember to catch correctly can easily mess up the whole process. Which then requires you to have multiple processes running at once (to remain responsive even if one process failed) plus a cronjob (or similar) to restart those that died. That's not optimal.

Typically, small parts of an online service are done in C++ (especially if they are performance critical and PHP/Java/Python/Node/etc. wouldn't suffice for the task at hand), and those you could easily do with Qt as well.
But I would advise against coding the part that handles actual user/API requests in C++.

Comment: I see your point for C. But C++ contains so much nice(and safe) features in it's later expansions. And if you use them you probably aren't that much less fault tolerant. But it's true, you HAVE to be more carefull.

Comment: That's always the thing with C++. You can do it all, but due to how much effort it is to make sure it is as safe as required, it would be easier to use a language that lets you focus on the actual task at hand instead of worrying about fault tolerance. There's a reason you don't see servers made with C++ in the wild (well, extremely rarely anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this really remind me the stability is more important than performance for a service application. But C++ is my only language. so is there any library（C++）or framework or toolkit to develop a server application? Or whether the using of signals base on moc will lead a problem of low speeding?

Comment: @jiaping you can write a simple performance test for direct function call and signal-slot connected call and check if there is an actual performance loss

Comment: @jiaping Honestly, if you know C++, you already know pretty much the most complicated language there is, at least in this field. Learning, for example, Java, PHP or Python now will come much easier to you than the other way around.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP, thanks for your advice, I will take it. But this project is time limited, I need to provide a basic version as soon as possible.

Comment: I've just did a simple test and it seems that on my CPU one signal call is approx `5e-6 ms` slower than the direct call.  So I really don't think this could be a problem.

Comment: thanks,Bearded Beaver, after thinking carefully about the moc, I agree.